# Why doesn't the output show up?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MaxAndMin(int* arr, int** max, int** min)
{
    int i;
    **max = **min = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (**max < arr[i])
        {
            **max = arr[i];
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (**min > arr[i])
        {
            **min = arr[i];
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int* maxPtr;
    int* minPtr;
    int arr[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("입력:");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    MaxAndMin(arr, &maxPtr, &minPtr);
    printf("%d %d", *maxPtr, *minPtr);
}
```

This is a problem with pointers. I want to print out the minimum and maximum values of arr, but I can't. It ends with just inputting the arr value, so where is the problem? Please let me know if there is anything wrong with setting the pointer variable

Comment: Right off the bat, `scanf` without checking return value -- you have no idea if `arr` was actually filled.

Comment: @DevSolar also using %d in scanf without a width specifier leads to UB.

Comment: @Fredrik: No it doesn't?

Comment: @DevSolar if the user enters a number to large or small for a int to hold it's actually UB. That is why you have to always us a width specifier for %d. One should use the strtol family instead.

Comment: `else continue;` is redundant because it always continues

Comment: @Fredrik: That would be the user entering an out-of-range value being the UB, not using `%d` without a field width (which isn't). But yes, for potentially malformed input, `fgets()` followed by manual parsing of the input is the better choice.

Comment: @DevSolar that is why I said "leads" to. We can't expect the user to know the exact range of allowed input, and since we the coder can't control it, we shouldn't make it possible for UB to happen, in my opinion.

Comment: @Fredrik: "Can lead to" would be the correct wording. "Leads to" is misleading. And a field width limitation is a very crude way to (try to) avoid it, as it limits the range of values you *can* legally enter, and the width would require either some `log10` arithmetic or some rather strange magic numbers. In over 20 years of maintenance coding, I have *never* seen `%d` used in `scanf()` with a field width.

Comment: @DevSolar yes that would be better phrasing.

Comment: @DevSolar I know me neither, yes a width specifier is not an optimal solution, one should use fgets followed by strtol instead, always, but it's more of a hassle so people don't.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have misunderstood something about emulating pass by reference in C.

The pointers `maxPtr` and `minPtr` are not initialized, they are pointing to *indeterminate* locations. And dereferencing them, which you do in your `MaxAndMin` function, leads to *undefined behavior* and likely crashes with the assignments.

You should declare `max` and `min` as plain `int` variables, and then pass pointers to them:

```
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
MaxAndMin(arr, &max, &min);
printf("%d %d", max, min);
```

And update the function to correspond to that change:

```
void MaxAndMin(int *arr, int *max, int *min)
{
    *max = *min = arr[0];
    // ... etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called "adding `&` and `*` at random until it seems to work", or "multiple `*` seem fishy", and we have all been there at one point. ;-)

```
int* maxPtr;
```

This is a *pointer-to-int*.

```
MaxAndMin(arr, &maxPtr, &minPtr);
```

This passes *address of pointer-to-int* to the function.

```
void MaxAndMin(int *arr, int** max, int** min)
```

Function takes *address of pointer-to-int* as argument.

```
**max = **min = arr[0];
```

Here it gets tricky: `max` is *address of pointer-to-int*. `*max` is therefore *pointer-to-int*, and `**max` is the *int* pointed to.

But here you got a problem. `*max`, and by extension, `maxPtr` in `main()`, *never was made to point at anything*. Writing an `int` value<sup>[1]</sup> to the indeterminate address that `maxPtr` happens to be pointing to is **undefined behavior**.

What you *want* is `max`, and by extension, `maxPtr` in `main()`, to *point* to *the address of `arr[0]`*:

```
*max = *min = &arr[0];
```

---

Generally speaking, changing your function's parameters is bad style. Sometimes necessary, but better avoided. A cleaner design of your function would be to declare a `struct { int * min; int * max; } min_max_t;`, and use that as return value from `MaxAndMin()`:

```
// Untested

struct
{
    int * min;
    int * max;
} min_max_t;

struct min_max_t MinAndMax( int * arr )
{
    struct min_max_t rc;

    rc.min = rc.max = &arr[0];

    // ...work with rc.min and rc.max

    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    {
        printf( "입력:" );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &arr[i] ) != 1 )
        {
            puts( "Non-numeric value entered!" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    struct min_max_t rc = MaxAndMin( arr );
    printf( "%d %d", *rc.max, *rc.min );
}
```

---

That being said, there is no actual need to work with pointers in the first place *as your function currently stands*. (You might need them at some later point, or be doing this as a learning exercise, both of which are valid considerations, I'm just saying that you can solve *this* problem without them.)

```
struct
{
    int min;
    int max;
} min_max_t;

struct min_max_t MaxAndMin( int * arr )
{
    struct min_max_t rc;
    rc.min = rc.max = arr[0];

    // assign values, instead of dealing with pointers

    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    // ...
    
    printf( "%d %d", rc.max, rc.min );
}
```

---

As for your double loop, note that you can check for `max` and `min` *in the same loop*, which is more effective. And you can do so without `continue`, which is `break`'s slightly less evil cousin:

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 5; ++i )
{
    if ( rc.min > arr[i] )
    {
        rc.min = arr[i];
    }

    if ( rc.max < arr[i] )
    {
        rc.max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

---

[1] `arr[0]`, which may or may not have been initialized by your `scanf()` -- you don't know because you didn't check `scanf()`'s return value...